# crowd vs. crowding

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

What is the difference between "crowd" and "crowding"? In the following sentence can we use both of them in place of each other?

> By building a branch campus, some of the **crowding (?=crowd)** on the
>   main campus may be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 'crowding'.

'Crowd' is a noun and simply means a large group of people

'Crowding' is the present participle of the verb 'to crowd' and is functioning as a noun in this sentence. Its meaning is the condition caused by a lot of people being within a comparatively small space at the same time. For example, it makes sense to say, "A large crowd in a confined space will cause crowding."

Comment: I thank you. Please take a look at this question too: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/190572/what-does-mean-it-there/190578#190578

Comment: @M. Afrashteh  I did look at it but I don't have a suitable answer for it. Sorry..